# Give repository access to non github users

Tags: github, repository

I want to know if there is a way to give access to a **private** repository to people who don't have a GitHub account. Like a link, app or integrating the GH account to some platform like Teams or Slack. The people I intend to share code with share a Microsoft Teams team with me and a corporation mail  name@comapny.com. Secure an official suggestions only please.

Comment: VPN solutions are also accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to give them access to clone a repository but not otherwise interact with it, then you can use read-only deploy keys to allow them to clone and fetch the repository via SSH.

Otherwise, if you need more access, then each user will need to have their own GitHub account.  It's intentional that users need their own accounts to properly enforce access controls and 2FA policies and to permit users to block and report bad actors.  GitHub does not permit accounts to be shared.